# PyMC3 variable dependent on result of another

Tags: statistics, pymc3

I am implementing a MCMC simulation for the first time and I have a variable that is defined based on the result of a previous variable. For instance if my bernoulli variable returns a 0, there will be a different value that gets fed into a deterministic variable than if it returns a 1.

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    x = pm.Bernoulli('x', .5)
    if x == 1:
        y = 1 
    elif x == 0:
        y = 2
    z = pm.Deterministic('z', y * 1000)
```

My issue is that neither of these if statements will get entered because x is not an integer, it is a distribution. Is there a way to get the sampled values of x? Or am I just thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you should use Theano's function `switch`

```py
with pm.Model() as model:
    x = pm.Bernoulli('x', .5)
    y = pm.math.switch(x, 1, 0)
    z = pm.Deterministic('z', y * 1000)
```

or a little bit more verbose

```py
with pm.Model() as model:
    x = pm.Bernoulli('x', .5)
    y = pm.math.switch(pm.math.eq(x, 1), 1, 0)
    z = pm.Deterministic('z', y * 1000)
```

`switch` evaluates the first argument, if true returns the second argument, otherwise the third one.

You can also use more than one `switch` if you have more than two conditions.

```py
with pm.Model() as model:
    x = pm.DiscreteUniform('x', 0, 2)
    y_ = pm.math.switch(pm.math.eq(x, 1), 1, 0)
    y = pm.math.switch(pm.math.eq(x, 2), 2, y_)
    z = pm.Deterministic('z', y * 1000)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. Are you aware of there being a way to implement this in an "if elif else" statement? Rather than just "if else"?

Comment: glad to help. I have updated my answer according to your comment.